# What do I set SONAR_RUNNER_HOME to in the Jenkins Global Tool Configuration for Sonarqube?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I'm trying to set up Sonarqube to run with Jenkins.  I have both Jenkins and Sonarqube installed on an Ubuntu virtual machine that's running on a Windows 10 Hyper-V host.  I downloaded Sonarqube to `/opt/sonarqube` and then followed the installation instructions at docs.sonarqube.org.  I am able to get to Sonarqube at myserver:9000 from my host machine and localhost:9000 from my guest machine, so Sonarqube is installed correctly and running as far as I can tell.

I installed the Sonarqube Scanner plugin in Jenkins, but I'm having trouble with the configuration of SONAR_RUNNER_HOME in the Global Tool Configuration.  I've tried setting it to both `/opt/sonarqube` and `/opt/sonarqube/bin/linux-x86-64`, but in both cases building my Jenkins projects results in the error `FATAL: SonarQube Scanner executable was not found for Local`

What do I set SONAR_RUNNER_HOME to in Jenkins Global Tool Configuration?

Comment: You have to locate installation path of Runner. Check `/opt/sonar-runner/bin/` path in terminal. If exists use `/opt/sonar-runner/bin/sonar-runner` to execute

Comment: What file should I look for?  Inside of `/opt/sonar-runner/bin` I have the folders `jsw-license`, `linux-x86-64`, `macosx-universal-64` and `windows-x86-64`

Comment: run `cd`, then `cd ..` and then `find . -name "sonar-scanner"` to find location of `sonar-runner`

Comment: I don't seem to have that file.  I tried searching the whole machine as well with `sudo find / -name sonar-scanner` and no results were returned.  Did I miss something during the installation?

Comment: You can use automatically `SonarQube Scanner installations` using **Maven** in **Global Tool Configuration** in Jenkins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Config installation from **Maven** in **Global Tool Configuration** in `SonarQube Scanner installations` in Jenkins.

Example how to use, where `SonarQubeServer` is name of `SonarQube servers` configuration in Jenkins `Configure System`. `SonarQubeScanner` name of `SonarQube Scanner installations`:

```
withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQubeServer') { 
    def sonarRunner = tool name: 'SonarQubeScanner', type: 'hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation'
    sh """
       ${sonarRunner}/bin/sonar-scanner \
       -Dsonar.projectKey=your_project_key \
       -Dsonar.sources=.
    """
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I didn't realize that Sonarqube and Sonar Runner were different things.  I downloaded Sonar Runner and it's working now.